# Substitution for $\iint \limits_{-a \le x,y \le a} f \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \,dx\,dy$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We want to compute $\displaystyle\frac{d}{da}\iint \limits_{-a \le x,y \le a} f \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \,dx\,dy $. Obviously it's necessary to make some appropriate substitution to get of $a$ from limits.

My attempts were :$(x+y)/2 = at , (x-y)/2 = av$, so we have $\displaystyle\frac{d}{da}\iint \limits_{-a \le x,y \le a} f \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \,dx\,dy = \frac{d}{da} \iint\limits_{|t+v| \le 1, |t-v|\le 1} 2a^2 f(at) \,dt \,dv$. This substitution looks good, but the area of integration become horrible.

Maybe there is a better approach ?  Just give a hint for a good substitution or some detail I miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$g(s,t) := \int_{-s}^s \int_{-t}^t f \Big( \frac{x+y}{2} \Big) \, dx dy$$
and note that by the multidimensional chain rule we would like to determine
$$g_s(a,a)+g_t(a,a).$$
The derivate of $g$ with respect to $t$, resp. $s$, can be determined by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus. In fact, this gives for example
$$g_s(s,t) = \int_{-t}^t f((s+x)/2) + f((x-s)/2) \, dx$$
and therefore
$$g_s(a,a)+g_t(a,a) = 2 \int_{-a}^a f((a+x)/2) + f((x-a)/2) \, dx.$$
Now change variables via $(a+x)/2 = z$, resp. $(x-a)/2 = z$, to get 
$$g_s(a,a)+g_t(a,a) = 4 \int_{0}^a f(x) dx + 4 \int_{-a}^0 + f(x) \, dx = 4 \int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx.$$